# can not cast values in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse the data from numbers

Enviroment: DataBricks Scala 2.12 Spark 3.1

I had chosen columns that were incorrectly parsed as Strings the reason is that sometimes numbers were written with coma sometimes with dot.

I am trying to first replace all commas to dots parse it as floats, create schema with type of floating numbers and recreate the dataframe but it does not work.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import sqlContext.implicits._ 
//temp is a dataframe with data that I included below
val jj = temp.collect().map(row=> Row(row.toSeq.map(it=> if(it==null) {null} else {it.asInstanceOf[String].replace( ",", ".").toFloat }) ))
val schemaa = temp.columns.map(colN=> (StructField(colN, FloatType, true)))
val newDatFrame = spark.createDataFrame(jj,schemaa)
```

Data screen
[image]

CSV

```
Podana aktywność,CRP(6 mcy),WBC(6 mcy),SUV (max) w miejscu zapalenia,SUV (max) tła,tumor to background ratio
218,72,"15,2",16,"1,8","8,888888889"
"199,7",200,"16,5","21,5","1,4","15,35714286"
270,42,"11,17","7,6","2,4","3,166666667"
200,226,"29,6",9,"2,8","3,214285714"
200,45,"13,85",17,"2,1","8,095238095"
300,null,"37,8","6,19","2,5","2,476"
290,175,"7,35",9,"2,4","3,75"
279,160,"8,36",13,2,"6,5"
202,24,10,"6,7","2,6","2,576923077"
334,"22,9","8,01",12,"2,4",5
"200,4",null,"25,56",7,"2,4","2,916666667"
198,102,"8,36","7,4","1,8","4,111111111"
"211,6","26,7","10,8","4,2","1,6","2,625"
205,null,null,"9,7","2,07","4,685990338"
326,300,18,14,"2,4","5,833333333"
270,null,null,15,"2,5",6
258,null,null,6,"2,5","2,4"
300,197,"13,5","12,5","2,6","4,807692308"
200,89,"20,9","4,8","1,7","2,823529412"
"201,7",28,null,11,"1,8","6,111111111"
198,9,13,9,2,"4,5"
264,null,"20,3",12,"2,5","4,8"
230,31,"13,3","4,8","1,8","2,666666667"
284,107,"9,92","5,8","1,49","3,89261745"
252,270,null,8,"1,56","5,128205128"
266,null,null,"10,4","1,95","5,333333333"
242,null,null,"14,7",2,"7,35"
259,null,null,"10,01","1,65","6,066666667"
224,null,null,"4,2","1,86","2,258064516"
306,148,10.3,11,1.9,"0,0002488406289"
294,null,5.54,"9,88","1,93","5,119170984"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the columns using Spark SQL `regexp_replace`. `collect` is not needed and will not give a good performance. You might also want to use `double` instead of `float` because some entries have many decimal places.

```
val new_df = df.select(
    df.columns.map(
        c => regexp_replace(col(c), ",", ".").cast("double").as(c)
    ):_*
)
```

Comment: Thank You ! yet I suppose it is in python can you give also example in scala?

Comment: This is in Scala. Why do you think it's in Python?

Comment: sorry regexp_replace thought is typical for python, You are right ! I just did not imported it it works thank You !!